# Trying to calculate a Win/Loss ratio based on specific cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to have a W:L ratio calculated into my Google sheet based on specific cells.

B2:M2 are manually updated to be either W or L

I would like O1 and P1 to reflect. So if there are 7 W's and 5 L's between B2:M2, I would like cell O1 to show (7)W and have cell P1 show (5)L

Any help would be appreciated. I'm relatively noobish to Google sheets

Image below!

[B2:M2 are manually updated to be either W or L](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aq43.png)

Comment: Can you share your research / method chosen to get the "7" ? (we can deal with the text combine later [edit] to add that info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`W` → `="("&COUNTIF(B2:M2,"=W")&") W"`

`L` → `="("&COUNTIF(B2:M2,"=L")&") L"`

To calculate just the number of `W` or `L`, just remove the text extras, it would look like this:

`W` → `=COUNTIF(B2:M2,"=W")`

`L` → `=COUNTIF(B2:M2,"=L")`